# Match specific string format - REGEXP_CONTAINS - GBQ Language

Tags: sql, regex, google-bigquery

I am trying to write a query that will only match table names that match a specific format, that format being as follows: FirstWord1_SecondWord2_ThirdWord3.

So all I am trying to get are table names that match the format of three alphanumeric words separated by underscores.

I've been struggling to workout the exact way to use REGEXP_CONTAINS to get the results I want. Below is the closest i've been able to get to, but it just wont return any results, despite the fact that I know there are tables that match the format I want to query for.

```
SELECT table_name as tablenames
FROM project.dataset.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE (
    REGEXP_CONTAINS(table_name, '^([[:alnum:]]+_[[:alnum:]]+_[[:alnum:]])$')
)
```

Any assistance with this would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your last  `[[:alnum:]]` is missing a `+` to indicate 1 or more matched characters.

```sql
SELECT table_name as tablenames
FROM project.dataset.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE (
    REGEXP_CONTAINS(table_name, '^([[:alnum:]]+_[[:alnum:]]+_[[:alnum:]]+)$')
)
```

or

```sql
SELECT table_name as tablenames
FROM project.dataset.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE (
    REGEXP_CONTAINS(table_name, '^[[:alnum:]]+_[[:alnum:]]+_[[:alnum:]]+$')
)
```

Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: ahh, I didn't realise that was what the + sign did, thanks!